# RoR Getting Started Second Module Cannot Add Commenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on the RoR Getting Started Tutorial and is stuck at Adding a Second Module. for the `f.submit`, the `:body` content is added to the database, but the `:commenter` doesn't seem to be added to the database. And I cannot find the bug. Anyone has any advise?

Below is my code for **show.html.erb**:

```
<h2>Add a Comment:</h2> 
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :commenter %><br><%= f.text_field :commenter %></p>
  <p><%= f.label :body %><br><%= f.text_area :body %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Paste your comments controller

Comment: Rustam, how did u edit my post to show in this format? looks much better than my original post. sorry. i'm new here is SO

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have :commenter in the comment_params method of your Comments controller.

Answer (score 0):

solved. it's an "eye problem". my :commenter was spelled :commmenter.

so sorry. thanks.